# Coloring the head in html

Tags: html, colors, head

Is it possible to color the head in an html file?

I tried doing the same thing you do to color the body,
`<body style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);">`.
I did the same with the head,
`<head style="background-color:rgb(40, 40, 40) ;">`.
But I ran the file and it doesn't work.

-Any help is appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am a complete beginner when it comes to html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but it doesn't do you any good unless you cause the `<head>` to be rendered (it is, by default, `display: none`).

```js
document.title="Example"; // Setting the title with JS because this is a Stack Snippet which expects the HTML provided to go in the <body>
```

```css
head {
    display: block;
    background: pink;
}

title {
    display: block;
}
```

Generally speaking, there shouldn't be anything in the `<head>` that you should *want* to be rendered.

It contains metadata *about* the document, not the document content itself.

Consequently, this rarely makes any sense except as an exercise in proving that CSS can touch any bit of markup in a page.

Comment: is it possible for you to show how you incorporate that snippet into the <head>?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started#adding_css_to_our_document